# Canvas radial gradient to match css radial gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've created two radial gradients that I would expect to be very similar: one using canvas operations and one using the css linear gradient. However, they end up looking very different. Is there any way to get the canvas gradient to match the css gradient, or is this simply an implementation difference that is too hard to work around?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('bar');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

const gradient = context.createRadialGradient(250, 250, 0, 250, 250, 250);

// Add the color stops
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(246,238,25,1)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(17,94,222,0.3)');

// Set the fill style and draw a rectangle
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(246, 238, 25, 1) 0, rgba(17, 94, 222, 0.3) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
<canvas id="bar"></canvas>
```

Comment: You can have the same radius https://jsfiddle.net/6eyo1wu2/  but I doubt you could do something for the gradient itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63223882/8620333

Comment: Thanks for the response. As for the radius, that helps, but for the gradient itself, this is basically what I was worried about. Oddly enough, it looks like Safari's canvas gradient implementation looks more similar to their css gradient implementation, but it sounds like they're doing it wrong given the canvas specification